# Repeat a function

Tags: python

```
from sys import exit

def answer():
    answer = raw_input("> ")
    if answer == "Yes" or answer == "yes":
        #going to next
        joint()
    elif answer == "No" or answer == "no":
        print "You still have something, I know..."
        again()
    else:
        fubar()

def again():
    again = raw_input("> ")
    if again == "Yes" or again == "yes":
        #going to next
        joint()
    elif again == "No" or again == "no":
        print "You still have something, I know..."
    else:
        fubar()

def fuck():
    print "Fubar'd!"

def joint():
    print "To be continue..."

def question():
    print "Hi duuuude..."
    raw_input("To say 'Hi' press Enter")
    print "Can you help me?"
    answer()

question()
```

Hi, can you help me with this? I`m trying to repeat the function "answer", when I get answer "NO". Im want to escape function "again"... And also is there a way to escape "answer == "Yes" or answer == "yes": " so no matter I write capital or small letter to accept the answer and not to write like a noob "Yes" or "yes"?

Comment: What's stopping you from replacing the `again()` with `answer()` in your `elif` part?

Answer (score 3):

This is usually achieved with a while loop.

Edit: As pointed out, while loops are nice and clear, and avoid recursion limits.

Never thought a simple answer would generate so many votes....

Lets give you an example

```
while True:
    ans = raw_input("Enter only y or n to continue").strip().lower()
    if ans == "y":
        print "Done!"
        break
    elif ans == "n":
        print "No?"
    else:
        print "Not valid input."
```

Comment: Apart from being cleaner, I think a while loop also avoids the potential "maximum recursion depth exceeded" errors that using recursion can cause.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to your problem is remove your `again` function, and recurse:

```
def answer():
    ans = raw_input("> ")
    if ans == "Yes" or ans == "yes":
        #going to next
        joint()
    elif ans == "No" or ans == "no":
        print "You still have something, I know..."
        answer() # again()
    else:
        fubar()
```

I had to rename your `answer` variable to `ans` so that it didn't clash with the function name.

---

For the second question, you want either:

```
if answer.lower() == "yes":
```

or

```
if answer in ("Yes", "yes"):
```